# Python Pyramid exception_view exception details

Tags: python, pyramid

I am using the Python Pyramid framework and am playing around with exception views.

For example

```
@exception_view_config(TypeError, renderer='json')
def type_error(exc, request):
    logger.info("There was a type error %s", str(exc)
```

However, the exception object doesn't have any useful information as to where the error occurred. Instead in the traceback it's `excview_tween [tweens.py:43]`

Is there a way to get more relevant information in this exception view?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do something with the `exc` arg, whether that is logging it or returning it in the view.

```py
class TypeError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg
```

```py
@exception_view_config(TypeError, renderer='json')
def type_error(exc, request):
    response =  Response('Type Error: %s' % exc.msg)
    response.status_int = 500
    return response
```

You will need to raise the exception with the `exc`.

```
raise TypeError("Here I am!")
```

See [Custom Exception Views](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/views.html#custom-exception-views).

Comment: Sorry I am doing that, I've updated the question. My problem is the traceback and exception object doesn't contain any overly useful information regarding where the exception took place.

Comment: I think you missed the `raise`. That's where you put whatever information you want.